# Android + GoogleMapsView - view won't render

Tags: java, android, google-api

I have a problem with google map view using Google API 1.6 - when i start my application using "debug" button in eclipse - the map is viewed properly (yet not always) but when i try starting my app with "Run" button - the map isn't viewed at all. I;m not talking about a gray screen with a grid on it - it's simply a black screen with nothing on it. It sometimes happens when I use the debg configuration too, yet not that often. I can't really work on debug all the time - the performance is too low. Of course i have my Maps API key and internet permission added - i did my homework.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    minDist = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    MapController mc;
    GeoPoint p;

    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview1);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    // set coordinators of Poznan old town
    mc = mapView.getController();

    double lat = Double.parseDouble(PoznanOldTownCoordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(PoznanOldTownCoordinates[1]);

    p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);

    // TODO: parameterize zoom
    mc.setZoom(17);

    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ghost_small);

    GetPointsTask getPointsTask = new GetPointsTask(this);
    getPointsTask.execute();

    // create an overlay that shows our current location
    myLocationOverlay = new LocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    // add this overlay to the MapView and refresh it
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
    mapView.postInvalidate();

}
```

Also, i get this on my Log.

```
01-19 23:24:08.307: W/ActivityManager(53): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{438226b0 beavers.miu/.activities.Map}
```

EDIT

I know what i did wrong.

```
GetPointsTask getPointsTask = new GetPointsTask(this);
getPointsTask.execute();
```

This is an AsyncTask, and you don't put AsyncTasks under onCreate() methods. That's where the error

```
01-19 23:24:08.307: W/ActivityManager(53): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{438226b0 beavers.miu/.activities.Map}
```

came from. I did some refactoring and now it works perfectly.

Comment: Are you testing on the emulator or a device?

Comment: On an emulator, forgot to mention.

Comment: You'll have to post your code so we can help identify the problem.

Comment: I added the code that i think is crucial here.